# error in installing matlab

Tags: software-installation, matlab

I have tried to download matlab program to my Ubuntu , but the installation was stop , and `MATLAB interface configuration` appear , and it ask me to enter location of matlab installation , So my question is : what I have to write in this location ?

Comment: how did you installed matlab?

Comment: @123456 from software center ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab can be installed as :

```
sudo apt-get install matlab-gdf dynare-matlab libpdl-io-matlab-perl matlab-support matlab-support-dev matlab2tikz
```